# How do you decipher the output of Perl's Benchmark::timestr?

Tags: perl, benchmarking

I'm using [Benchmark](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Benchmark), which outputs:

`1 wallclock secs ( 0.22 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.22 CPU) @ 4545454.55/s (n=1000000)`

can anyone explain each of the numbers above with more detail?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- 1 wallclock secs

It took 1 second of real time to run the benchmark.

- 0.22 usr

0.22 seconds on the CPU in user mode

- 0.00 sys

0 seconds of CPU time taken up by the kernel

- 0.22 CPU

Total CPU time

- n=1000000

the number of iterations of the benchmark that were run in that time

- 4545454.55/s

The total number of iterations that could be run in 1 second of CPU time (this is iterations/CPU time)